# Socket.io pinginterval's impact on server performance

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have an app that connects to a node.js server using socket.io.
I'm having some trouble with users disconnecting due to the bad network.
And due to this issue, I would like to show the client the current latency on the server, just so the client is aware if they have a "bad connection".

My server uses defaults currently and pings the client every 25 seconds.
I would like to set my pingInterval to 3-5 seconds instead to show a more updated latency-status.

But I'm unsure if this could affect the server?
I have peaked at 800 simultaneous users being connected at one time.

Could this become a performance issue, if the server has to ping 800 clients every 3-5 seconds instead of every 25 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I have now changed the pingInterval of the server from 25000(default) to 2500, and this seems to have no impact on performance (testet with 290 simultaneous users)

Comment: what's the status now? does it have any impact with more users?

Comment: No, lowering the interval had almost no impact on performance.

Comment: I have peaked with 1500 users connected simultaneous, and everything ran just fine.

Comment: In my case lowering down, ping-interval had not affected the chrome users on high-end devices but greatly affected embedded systems, they kept trying to connect again as the server was considering them disconnected because of slow processing power they can't pong back in time.

Comment: as you have said you have peaked 1500 users, can you please tell me what happens when more user connects? ie impact on RAM and Processor usages of server

Comment: I believe the ping interval is part of your total timeout. So if your timeout is 25s and your ping time is 25s you have 50s before disconnected, so maybe you could set your timeout higher?

In my application I also had some issues with users who kept disconnecting. This was caused by some issues in the connection that could not upgrade from polling to socket which is the default behaviour. But I fixed it by defining my transports like this:
io(url+':'+port, {'timeout' : 10000, 'transports' : ['websocket', 'polling']})

The ram usage was a bit higher with more users, but nothing much.

Comment: Polling never worked for me, I had to strictly use WebSocket as the primary and only transport, you have helped me a lot. I have upvoted your answer thanks.